# What is the best way to write a function having many arguments?

Tags: functions, notation

I'd like to ask you guys what is the best way to write a function having a sequence of arguments?

If a function has $x$ and $y$ as its arguments then we write,
$$
f\left(x,y\right)
$$
What if we have a function that takes $x_i$, $\forall i=1,\cdots,N$ ? I can try
$$
f\left(\mathbf x\right),
$$
where $\mathbf x = [x_1, x_2, \cdots, x_N]^\mathsf T$.

How about that $f$ takes $\mathbf x_i$, $\forall i=1,\cdots,N$ ? Is it just okay that
$$
f\left(\mathbf x_i\right), \forall i=1,\cdots,N ?
$$

Otherwise,
$$
f\left(\mathbf X\right),
$$
where $\mathbf X = [\mathbf x_1,\mathbf x_2, \cdots, \mathbf x_N]^\mathsf T$.

But, I don't like to introduce a new symbol $\mathbf X$, and even in the function $f$, the $\mathbf x_i$s are manipulated individually not all together as a matrix, e.g.,
$$
f\left(\mathbf x_1, \mathbf x_2, \cdots, \mathbf x_N\right) = \sum_{i=1}^N \sigma\left(\mathbf W\mathbf x_i + \mathbf b\right),
$$
something like that.

Listing all the arguments as above is too verbose to me. Which way do you prefer to write a function like that?

Comment: Have you considered writing $f:(\mathbb R^N)^N\to \mathbb R^N$?

Comment: @JackozeeHakkiuz Yes, of course. The first introduction of $f$ can be written in that way. But, how about when I define $f$ explicitly, what $f$ takes specifically and which operations are applied to those arguments? I need some simple and neat ways to do it.

Comment: It is extremely common in the physics literature (especially stat mech) to write $f(x)$ with $x=(x_1,x_2,\dots)$.

Answer (score 1):

For your last example I would just write something like

Fix a matrix $W\in M_n(\mathbb R)$, a vector $b\in\mathbb R^n$ and a function $\sigma:\mathbb R^n\to \mathbb R$. Define a new function $f:\mathbb R^{n\times n}\to\mathbb R$ by the formula
$$f(x) = \sum_{i=1}^n \sigma(Wx_i+b)$$
where $x=(x_1,\dots,x_n)$ and $Wx_i$ denotes matrix multiplication.